# pandas everyline regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding=utf-8
df=pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,'2015-11入住,2015-11-12离开'],[2,3,'2016-11入住,2016-11-2离开']],columns=['a','b','c'])
print df
```

I want get the result:

```
   a  b           c
0  1  2  2015-11-12
1  2  3   2016-11-2
```

I want to use regex

```
df.c=re.search('((\d+)-){2}(\d+)',df.c).group()
```

I know this exprssion is ERROR：re module is used to str,but the df.c is a pandas.series,but I don't know how to write regex for  pandas's every line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` built-in regex match [.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
df['c'] = df.c.str.extract('(\d+-\d+-\d+)')
```

[image]